# How to handle errors with HttpWebRequest in WP7?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

When using the WebClient class you can check for errors and empty results by using

> e.error != null

and

> e.result == null

respectively. How would I handle this using the HttpWebRequest class? All examples seem to omit this yet its vital in applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpWebRequest` uses the `IAsyncResult` and Begin/End pairs for an operation.

You will have passed a Callback method delegate to Begin operation and then in that callback you call the End method for that operation.  To catch an error that may have occured in the asynchronous part of the operation you place a try block around your call to the End method.

For example when calling `BeginGetResponse` you might pass this call back:-

```
 private void Callback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 {
     try 
     {
         HttpWebResponse resp =  (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         //Something bad happened during the request
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a REST client Framework like [Spring.Rest](http://www.springframework.net/#spring-rest-1.0.0-released) ("Spring.Rest" on NuGet), it will do all this boilerplate code for you :

```
RestTemplate client = new RestTemplate("http://exemple.com/");
client.GetForObjectAsync<string>("path/", r =>
  {
    if (r.Error != null)
    {
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try-catch for that.

```
try {
   // Create a web request for an invalid site. Substitute the "invalid site" strong in the Create call with a invalid name.
     HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("invalid site");

    // Get the associated response for the above request.
     HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    myHttpWebResponse.Close();
}
catch(WebException e) {
    Console.WriteLine("This program is expected to throw WebException on successful run."+
                        "\n\nException Message :" + e.Message);
    if(e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
        Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx

Comment: Silverlight does not do synchronous Web operations, there is no `GetResponse` in silverlight only `[Begin/End]GetResponse`.

Comment: If you go to the link (which is where the code snip comes from), you'll see the concept is the same: using try-catch for GetResponse. Sync or async operation doesn't matter here.